# Cast operator in C Binary to Double

Tags: c++, casting, operator-keyword

I am trying to write an operator to cast binary number to `double` but got errors.

This my code:

```
double operator double*()(BinaryOctet b) {
    double double_b = (double)binaryToInt(b);

    return double_b;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you haven't done so already, please take the [tour] and visit the [ask] section of the [help]. When asking, it is important to provide enough details to help diagnose the problem. Since you are asking about code that doesn't compile, it means providing the exact error message, and a short (but not too short) piece of code that gives exactly that error. For a detailed explanation read about how one should create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgotten one very important thing: Conversion operators *must* be members of the class you're converting from.

It's not possible to have non-member conversion operators. Or conversion operators that takes arguments for unrelated types.

So to be correct it should be a member of the `BinaryOctet` class:

```
class BinaryOctet
{
public:
    // ...
    operator double()
    {
        return ...;
    }
};
```

If `BinaryOctet` isn't a class (or `struct`) then you can not have a conversion operator.

I recommend looking through e.g. [this operator overloading reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) for general operator-overloading details, and [this user-conversion operator reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) for more details about conversion operators.

---

Also note that conversion operators doesn't have a return type. It is deduced by the compiler.

Comment: I would not answer such a low quality question, to be honest. OP should have provided much more.

Comment: @SergeyA I think [we should be nicer to beginners](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/).

Comment: We can be nice without indulging low effort, though

Comment: Being nicer to beginners and promoting low-effort question is not the same thing in my view.

Comment: I don't think a MCVE or showing the errors would make much difference in this case. It's quite clear that the OP misunderstands conversion operators on a level where no MCVE or error list would help us write any better answers.